# What flame is SpaceX's Hans Koenigsmann describing in his presentation?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, merlin-1d, exhaust

At `35:46` in part 1 of this recording of SpaceX's Hans Koenigsmann's talk at IAC 2018, he says something like:

> The green stuff that you see is TEA-TEB, that’s the ignition fluid that they use.
>
> The flame that goes a little bit like up and down, *that’s the xxx; the yyy flame*. The main flame just goes straight down.

What are the terms represented here as xxx and yyy? If the terms are not obvious, a little further explanation is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related flames: [Why are exhaust flames “jumping around” the bases of the Falcon-9 engine nozzles; NROL-76?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22305/12102)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jumping flame was the gas generator exhaust.

You can see that as the bronze-ish coloured smaller cylinder on the side of the engine in this picture of Merlin 1D engines in the factory.

[image: Merlin 1Ds on the factory floor]

You can see how it changes in size and shape from the Merlin 1C in this image:

[image: Merlin 1C]

This is really obvious on the last Falcon 1, which used a Merlin 1C but was never flown, and recently was moved from storage to the Hawthorne factory, and there is a great shot of the F1 next to the F9 on display.

[image: F1 next to F9 display]

The Merlin engine burns fuel/oxidizer in a separate combuster, whose output/power is used to run the fuel pump.

Rockets needs gobs and gobs of fuel/oxidizer at rates that are astonishing.  The SSME on the Space Shuttle high pressure turbo pump put out 23,260 hp (17.34 MW) of power. That is a lot.

The Merlin has about 1/3 the total thrust of the SSME, but uses denser fuels and a single turbo pump for both fuel and oxidizer but still needs to move a lot of liquids very quickly.

On the Merlin, the exhaust is vented over the side from the gas generator. That is the flame you are seeing.